# How to configure SQL credentials while runsql Command in CMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I am trying to use command `runsql` for executing a SQL file from the command prompt. I can see the syntax of runsql is

```
runsql [SQL Server] [Script file] [optional output file]
```

[see the screenshot for the exact syntax of runsql command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57Drk.png)

But all I'm struggling to understand is where the username and password for SQL Server is configured. What default credentials it will use and how can I change it?

Comment: What is `runsql`?  The command line tool for SQL Server is sqlcmd. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Looks like runsql is for DB2 iSeries. Is the tag incorrect or the function?

Comment: Looks like runsql is some customized command that someone in my organization created it very long back. The whole IT team is changed now and not sure how the Credentials were being passed for making a SQL connection. 
The syntax is mentioned as above. It requires only Server name and SQL file path.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Runsql is a customized command that our organization created and I found the configuration files path in the Environment Variables and changed the password there.